# Xcode : how to run a program in Simulator window ?

Tags: objective-c

I'm running **MAC OS 10.6 SDk**  , **Xcode version 3.2.3**

When running a program , " Simulator " option is not showing.

I can open the simulator separately by going to platforms and choosing IPhone Simulator platform.

How can I just link this to have my program open in Simulator window instead of the normal one? Any Ideas ??

Comment: What do you need the simulator is you are using the mac os sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you would need to be coding to an iOS SDK in order to use the simulator.